# JSF + Spring integration

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2, dependency-injection

I have an application with `JSF 2.2` and `Spring 4.3`
with these components: `web-module`, `service-module`, `service-module-interface` and ear.

1. In the `service-module` I have configured a `SpringConfiguration` class.
2. In `ear` I have included the `web-module` and `service-module`
3. The `web-module` has a dependency with `service-module-interface` (they are the interfaces of the `spring @Service` class in `service-module`). Below the a snippet of `web.xml`:

   ```
    <context-param>
     <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
     <param-value>         org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
     </param-value>
   ```

   ```
    <context-param> <!-- my spring configuration class -->
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>com.ipdb.datamodel.conf.SpringConfiguration</param-value>
   ```

   ```
       <listener><listener><listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class></listener>

   <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   ```

I cannot to inject with `@Autowired` in a `Backing Bean` in `web module`. I have this error: `No qualifying bean of type`. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Your web.xml is not welformed xml. `context-param` is not closed. `listener-class` is not within `listener`, for example. Regardless of all that, why do you need to mix JavaEE and Spring? (my personall opinion :-))

Comment: In application the web.xml is well formed. I want inject the spring service in Backing bean.

Comment: [This](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-jsf-2-integration-example-using-autowired-annotation) example might help to integrate Spring and JSF. Good luck :-)

Comment: Now I have No qualifying bean of type in Backing bean, but I'm sure that bean in SpringConfiguration class is started but the backing bean is not in same context

Comment: I solved the solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551532/spring-autowiredrequired-true-is-null?noredirect=1#comment64493794_38551532)