# Spring @Autowired(required = true) is null

Tags: spring, jsf, dependency-injection

I have a webmodule with JSF 2 end Spring 4.3. In a backing bean I use `@Autowired` for DI of a service of a JAR. In EAR module there are WAR, JAR with `@Service` Spring and JAR with Spring configuration file.

Below a `web.xml` snippet:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>locatorFactorySelector</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:beanRefContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
        <param-value>sharedContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

`applicationContext.xml`:

```
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:spring-configured />
<!-- package of @Service class in jar module in EAR-- >
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ipdb.service" />
```

beanRefContext.xml:

> ```
> <bean id="sharedContext" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">    <constructor-arg>
>     <list>
>         <value>spring-ctx.xml</value>
>     </list>
> </constructor-arg>    </bean>
> ```

When I Use `@Autowired(required=null)` in a Backing Bean the value is `null` (there is not any exception). My JSF bean

```
@Component
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PortfolioController {


    @Autowired(required = true)
    private PortfolioService portfolioService;

...
```

Can you help me, please.

Comment: It's not a Spring bean and Spring isn't managing or autowiring it.

Comment: As your question was initially tagged with [spring-mvc], here's some food for thought: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18744910

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PortfolioController` is considered a `JSF` context bean adding `@Component` to `@ManagedBean` is totally wrong you can't mark same class as bean in two different contexts (`JSF` and `Spring` ).

Two solutions either make `PortfolioController` a spring bean thus remove the `@ManagedBean` and `@ViewScoped` or inject `PortfolioController` via `JSF` injection annotation `@ManagedProperty`

```
@ManagedProperty("#{portfolioService}")
private PortfolioService portfolioService;
```

Comment: Ok, I have deleted `@Autowired` with `@ManagedBean`. The implementation service is detected now, but I have this error: `Cannot convert com.ipdb.service.portfolio.impl.PortfolioServiceImpl@5276229c of type class com.ipdb.service.portfolio.impl.PortfolioServiceImpl to interface com.ipdb.service.PortfolioService`. `PortfolioServiceImpl` implements `PortfolioService`. Can you help me please?

Comment: I solved, it was a dependacy problem in pom ;)

Answer (score 0):

if the `applicationContext.xml` is in your jar dependency, then you need to add asterisk after classpath:

```
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

With the asterisk  spring search files `applicationContext.xml` anywhere in the classpath not only the current project.